# How to position line label right of a line in pyqgis?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am using pyqgis to dynamically label layers and show them. However, I could not set the label position to be right of line as shown in the image below. 
[image]
How could I do it?

Below is the code:

```
                layer.setCustomProperty("labeling", "pal")
                line_layer.setCustomProperty(
                    "labeling/fieldName", "measurement")

                line_layer.setCustomProperty(
                    "labeling/placement", QgsPalLayerSettings.AboveLine
                )

                line_layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontSize", "10")
                line_layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/bufferDraw", True)
                line_layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/enabled", True)
                line_layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/drawLabels", True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, labeling/placement does not refer to that, it refers to "Parallel", "Curved" or "Horizontal", so using "AboveLine" here will not work. You need to use "labeling/placementFlags".

Then the "Right of line" label is only a change in the displayed text when the "Line orientation dependent position" setting is checked. Underneath it is the "BelowLine" flag that is used.

This means you have to use:

```
line_layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/placementFlags", QgsPalLayerSettings.BelowLine)
```