# Using label placement via PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, labeling, line, curved

In QGIS 3.28 I am trying to align my labels along line features but cannot get them in curved mode. I tried:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.placement = Qgis.LabelPlacement.Curved
settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
settings.isExpression = True
settings.fieldName = "NAME"

settings.displayAll = True
layer.setLabeling(QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(settings))
layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

but this did not work and the labels still appear as *"Parallel"* when checking layer properties.

Is there any way to change this? I am using this in the context of rule-based labeling but it simply seems not to work. What do I miss here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `QgsVectorLayer` class has no method like `placement`. However, the `QgsPalLayerSettings` does.

I suppose you are trying to apply this [`LabelPlacement`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgis.html#a3acc05d5f279798221dd3f0f5ceae573a217bfa6ed442f0d3942bc6b1dd9323cb) mode.

Just add this `settings.placement = Qgis.LabelPlacement.Curved` statement into your code:

```py
from qgis.utils import iface
from qgis.core import Qgis, QgsPalLayerSettings, QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling

layer = iface.activeLayer()

settings = QgsPalLayerSettings()
settings.isExpression = False
settings.fieldName = "NAME"
settings.displayAll = True
settings.placement = Qgis.LabelPlacement.Curved

labeling = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(settings)

layer.setLabeling(labeling)
layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

*Note:* There is no need in `settings.isExpression = True`, because `"NAME"` is a simple field without any add-ons.

I am using QGIS 3.28.10-Firenze.

---

**References:**

- [Reading and setting label settings in PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273266/reading-and-setting-label-settings-in-pyqgis)
- [Setting QgsExpression for QgsPalLayerSettings in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167163/setting-qgsexpression-for-qgspallayersettings-in-qgis)
- [Vector layer labeling not working using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401508/vector-layer-labeling-not-working-using-pyqgis)
- [How to position line label right of a line in pyqgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/275135/how-to-position-line-label-right-of-a-line-in-pyqgis)

Comment: Yep - that was the solution. Excellent thanks!